# Site automatically refreshing

Tags: browser, web, refresh

Since upgrading to Firefox 4, [my site](http://www.caribonix.com/) has been automatically refreshing. I haven't written any script for it to do so. It also adds "#" to the end of the URL. This does not happen in IE9, Chrome, Safari, or Opera; only FF 4.

Why does this happen? How can it be solved?

Comment: ITs not happening In my firefox 4...I have waited for 10 min..

Comment: thanks so what could be cause of this? it's really frustrating

Comment: some how it has stopped doing it. Don't know how it started and don't know how it solved it self.

Comment: hahaha....Its goood that it works out itself...:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by a script Google analytical embedded into the site when I enabled their new heat map feature upon disabling it and clearing my cache the problem was solved